# Can firestore wherefield be set later in code?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a database connection in my swift application with a few different where fields so that I can apply filters on my call. I tried a few things, but what I got now is this:

```
class RewardViewModel { 

private let collectionRewards = "rewards"

var rewards = [Reward]()

private var db = Firestore.firestore() 

func fetchFilteredRewards(filters: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
    self.rewards.removeAll()
    var filteredDb = db.collection(collectionRewards)    

    for (name, value) in filters {          
        switch name {
        case "min":
            filteredDb = db.collection(collectionRewards).whereField("price", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: value)
            print("nminus", name) 

        case "max":
            filteredDb = filteredDb.whereField("price", isLessThanOrEqualTo: value)
            print("maxim", name)         

        case "category":
            filteredDb.whereField("category", equal: value)

        case "type":
            filteredDb.whereField("type", equal: value)
        default:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating an firestore instance then using it in the fetchFilteredRewards. The filtered rewards take in a dictionary (more in the next code piece). What I want to do is add all items in the dictionary to the db.collection, but I have few different rules to add such as "less than" or "greater than" that's why I used a switch case, so that's like this basically: (it works when I paste it directly behind the db.collection, but when I assign new wherefields later in the code it does not add the wherefields to the query, so I get all results instead of a filtered result)

```
   var filteredDb = db.collection(collectionRewards).whereField("price", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 500).whereField("price", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 600)
```

My controller adds all filters to a dictionary and sends it to the viewmodel:

```
let filtersDictionary: [String: Any] = ["min": 600, "max": 800] 

rewardViewModel?.fetchFilteredRewards(filters: filtersDictionary)
```

For now I want it to work with a price between 600 and 800, later the category and type will be added to the filters.

Some pictures of the app for clarity:

[image]
[image]

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Also the firebase docs says that adding wherefields like this should work (on line 1004), but I guess I am still implementing it the wrong way: https://github.com/firebase/snippets-ios/blob/6441eff381af56888cfcfd3f97acb4384e69f6fc/firestore/swift/firestore-smoketest/ViewController.swift#L1008-L1013

Answer (score 0):

For people having the same problem. You have to make a reference variable. I tried it with DocumentReference, but that did not work for me so I used Query as the reference:

```
func fetchFilteredRewards(filters: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
    self.rewards.removeAll()
    var ref: Query? = nil
    let filteredDb = db.collection(collectionRewards)
    

    for (name, value) in filters {
       
        switch name {
        case "min":
            ref = filteredDb.whereField("price", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: value)
        case "max":
            ref = filteredDb.whereField("price", isLessThanOrEqualTo: value)
        case "category":
            ref = filteredDb.whereField("price", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: value)
        case "type":
            ref = filteredDb.whereField("price", isLessThanOrEqualTo: value)
        default:
            return
        }
    }
    
    ref?.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("something went wrong::: \(err)")
        } else {
            if let documents = querySnapshot?.documents {

                for doc in documents {
                   
                    let title = doc.data()["title"] as? String ?? ""
                    print(title)
                    let imageUrl = doc.data()["imageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
                    let brandName = doc.data()["brandName"] as? String ?? ""
                    let productDescription = doc.data()["productDescription"] as? String ?? ""
                    let price = doc.data()["price"] as? Int ?? 0
                    self.rewards.append(Reward(brandName: brandName, imageUrl: imageUrl, price: price, productDescription: productDescription, title: title))
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```